# Talend: JET timeout error when running a job

Tags: talend

After Talend Studio installation, I try to run a job but it fails because of a JET timeout. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your talend installation directory and check the folder:
/plugins/org.talend.designer.components.localprovider_{your-talend-id}/components.

Then add the folder "user" and restart your talend studio.

It helps me.